# C# Persisting Objects Between User Sessions Without using a database

Tags: c#, object-persistence

I'm making a simple Winforms that reads in a text file and does some parsing to put it into C# objects that are then manipulated by my app.

I would like to parse the file once. Then go away for a week, come back and load all the objects back into my app.

I don't want to persist to database thus was hoping there was some sort of simple object persistance framework I could hook into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Look into the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) for this. If you want a file that isn't XML you can try the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

You simply add the [`DataContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`DataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attributes to tell the serializer how to manage the serialization.

If your objects will not change (new/old/renamed properties and visibility) and you don't care to read the serialization format, you can try the [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).

---

There are several older serializers in the frame work (`XmlSerializer`, `BinaryFormatter` and more), but the best control over the serialization format will be with the above).

Comment: He could also use basic binary serialization. Simpler to implement, but less flexible; if he doesn't expect the object's structure to change and the persisted result doesn't have to be human-readable, it's a good option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use application settings or user settings. Its pretty easy with the wizard that can be found under the projects properties. [here is the tutorial for it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could just serialize them to an XML file.  Simple, quick and easy (unless someone hacks the file).

Comment: XML serialization is sloooooowwww, but if thats not a problem, then you encrypt the contents to keep users out of it.

Comment: It's not slow unless his Winforms app has a rediculous amount of data.

Comment: @Muad'Dib - Show us the numbers, please.

Comment: @oded [here is a link](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) to someone who has done the testing. MS "official" word is that XML serialize is tons slower. (they told us this at the Dec 2010 silverlight firestarter event)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do this would be to serialize the objects directly to a file, using the `BinaryFormatter` class. You'll need to make sure that all your types are marked as `[Serializable]` but this approach is fast and easy.

Here is a simple example of a "read" and "write" method for an arbitrary object graph:

```
private void SerializeToFile(string fileName, object o)
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, o);
    }
}

private object DeserializeFromFile(string fileName)
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
    {
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Other approaches include XmlSerialization (the `XmlSerializer` class) - better if you want to the serialized objects to be human readable or editable, or using the newer `DataContractSerializer`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest non-DB method of storing object state is serialization. Mark your class as either Serializable or a DataContract, then use a BinaryFormatter (or DataContractSerializer if you used the DataContract) to convert the object into a persistable state. That can then be saved to a file that you can load when the app starts back up and deserialize in a similar fashion. Be aware that the class's members, including child classes, must be serializable in the same way, and that you will lose any references to non-serialized elements such as pointers and delegate references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialization as sugested before.

A good place to save the data in is Windows's LocalData folder -

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with a database ? If you do not want to have a full engine with its setup and associated problems, maybe you can take a look at "file" based databases...

My first toughs are :

- SqlCompact
- Access databases
- SqlLite

...

Depending the complexity of your objects to persist, it can be a good solution.